# gcc makes makefile but can't build with it

Tags: gcc, makefile, solaris

I am porting a big C++ project from Windows to Solaris 9, using Eclipse 3.3.1.1 and gcc. It makes a makefile, but then it can't read it:

```
gcc -f /export/home/MyPath/Debug/makefile -v 

Using built-in specs.
Target: sparc-sun-solaris2.10    
Configured with: /_support/develop_tools/Sol10_gcc/gcc-4.2.4/configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc4.2.4 --with-as=/usr/ccs/bin/as --with-ld=/usr/ccs/bin/ld --enable-shared --enable-languages=c,c++
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.4
/usr/local/gcc4.2.4/libexec/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/4.2.4/collect2 -V -Y P,/usr/ccs/lib:/usr/lib -Qy /usr/local/gcc4.2.4/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/4.2.4/crt1.o /usr/local/gcc4.2.4/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/4.2.4/crti.o /usr/ccs/lib/values-Xa.o /usr/local/gcc4.2.4/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/4.2.4/crtbegin.o -L/usr/local/gcc4.2.4/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/4.2.4 -L/usr/ccs/lib -L/usr/local/gcc4.2.4/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/4.2.4/../../.. /export/home/MyPath/Debug/makefile -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lc -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lc /usr/local/gcc4.2.4/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/4.2.4/crtend.o /usr/local/gcc4.2.4/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/4.2.4/crtn.o
ld: Software Generation Utilities - Solaris Link Editors: 5.9-1.393
ld: fatal: file /export/home/MyPath/Debug/makefile: unknown file type
ld: fatal: File processing errors. No output written to a.out
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? I think maybe the versions are incompatible, but I am new to this. I set it to use gcc compilers instead of Solaris, but it didn't help. What can it be?

Answer (score 2):

The Makefile itself should not be compiled using gcc, rather, it contains instructions how to invoke gcc.

Comment: Done. I should have been using make, gnu make. One of my colleagues had placed it in an unexpected place. Now I know where it is I put it in my path and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try "make -f /export/home/MyPath/Debug/makefile -v"